# Compare two files and add rule to iptables

Tags: command-line, bash, iptables, text-processing

I have two files.

A. Keys.txt

```
<string>
<string>
..
..
```

B. Hellos.txt

```
<string> <ip address> <ip address>
<string> <ip address> <ip address>
..
..
```

I want to perform the task - if a string (column1) in `hellos.txt` is found in `keys.txt` then add the firewall rule to allow packets for for those ip addresses.

I have tried to `grep -v -F -x -f file1 file2` but I fail to get the correct output.

EDIT: 
I updated to use awk, however I am not able to add the rules to iptables.

1. This prints out the matching line

   ```
   sudo awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt
   ```
2. This attempts to add a rule to iptables but is unsuccesful

   ```
   sudo awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){iptables -I INCOMING -j -s$2 ALLOW}' keys.txt hellos.txt
   ```

Comment: What about `grep -F -f file1 file2`?

Comment: I used awk and was able to find the matching line. However am not able to add the ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the edit,

The following command can be used to match the common string in the files

```
sudo awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt
```

To further improve output use the `awk -v OFS='\n' '` option with a pipe to print the ip address to a file. From there on it is simple to add rules to iptables.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt | awk -v OFS='\n' '{ print $2, $3 }'> improved_address.txt
```